Screenshot of the Launchpad?
Trying to take a pic of my Launchpad icon arrangement but when pressing any combination of keystrokes... the Launchpad disappears.
I've been a Mac use for many years, and am OK with simple terminal commands, but nothing  complex.
iMac 24 M1, Ventura 13.6.7

What's the question?

How to take a screenshot of the Launchpad window?

Shift Command 4 works great for me. See my answer for some hints. Since you didn't explain what "any combination of keystrokes" means for you, we might need an edit to understand more fully your challenge here.

Solved. When using the "Selection" option in the Screenshot utility with the  delay timer, and then pressing any of the shortcut keys when the Launchpad is displayed... no pic is generated.
However, if the "Capture Entire Screen" option is selected, and with a delay timer set, then a small, moveable camera icon appears. Position the camera icon on the Launchpad icon on the Dock, click, and when the Launchpad is displayed a pic is generated.
Works fine in Ventura 13.6.7. Thank you for the guidance.

I press shift command 4 and can select the part of the screen I desire.

I am on macOS Sonoma 14.6 but am quite certain this behavior should be the same for the last 3 major versions of macOS. Are you sure you haven't added some third party screen capture software or changed the default keybindings?
You might want to make a new user account to test if that account freshly created works to help troubleshoot why your Mac isn't working like intended.

Check your settings and test Screenshots in Finder or other apps: 
You could use the screenshot app to set an option for a 5 or 10 second delay if you absolutely need to keep your keys off the keyboard and get this data.


Thanks, but when the Launchpad is displayed, and any key is pressed (including any of the shortcut screenshot keys) the Launchpad disappears. If I activate the screenshot utility first and then go to the Launchpad, that doesn't work. My system is 100% stock.

I understand your situation, but this isn't normal. Shift Command 3 and Shift Command 4 work great. Have you tried Screenshot app where you can set a 5 second delay? You shouldn't need it but perhaps you can move forward while you understand what setting or app you have that's causing Launchpad to disappear.

As a hint @VinceG the default behavior of LaunchPad is that any keyboard input goes to the search box at the top of the window. So if you type only the letter m - you should see filtered results like Mail, Messages, Maps, Music, etc... and not that the app gets dismissed and you go back to the Finder. Is this reproducible after a normal shut down and then start up on your iMac?

actually when the Launchpad is displayed, and any of the screenshot keystrokes are pressed (or any keys) the search box at the top of the screen is activated. but it doesn't go back to the Finder as you mentioned. the Launchpad is still displayed.

how do I set a timer for the screenshot utility?

Options is the thing to click in English - see the last link and open the screenshot app

I've been mildly hesitant about upgrading to Sonoma because I have a stable Photoshop platform, but upgrading may be the solution. I'll do so later and post an update. thanks for the suggestions.

I would not upgrade for just this. Good news is you can get a solid backup or install Sonoma on an external and test before you commit - going back on macOS is viable for most people @VinceG so glad the timer worked for you
